# Laravel 5: API routes + wildcard route results in unexpected behavior

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-5.7

I am trying to build a React application backed with Laravel API, so essentially using a wildcard route for client-side routing, and then simply an API route group to process data.

This is my `routes/web.php` file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/payment/redirect/{orderId}', ['as' => 'mollie.redirect', 'uses' => 'Controller@index']);
Route::get('/{any}', ['as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'Controller@index'])->where('any', '.*');
```

And this is my `routes/api.php` file:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('/orders', ['as' => 'orders.store', 'uses' => 'OrdersController@store']);
Route::post('/payment/webhook', ['as' => 'mollie.webhook', 'uses' => 'OrdersController@webhook']);
```

which results in:

[image]

But, whenever I try to make a request at `POST api/orders` this is what I get in Postman:

[image]

Which is what `Controller@index` should respond, not `OrdersController@store`, which should be a JSON response.

This is my `OrdersController` code:

```
<?php 

namespace Http\Controllers;

use Customer;
use Http\Requests\OrderCreateRequest;
use Order;
use Product;
use Services\CountryDetector;
use Services\LanguageService;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class OrdersController extends Controller
{
    const ERROR_PRODUCT_COUNTRY_UNAVAIALBLE = 'errors.products.country_unavailable';

    public function store(OrderCreateRequest $request, LanguageService $language, Order $orders, Customer $customers, Product $products)
    {
        $customer = $customers->firstOrCreate(['email' => $request->input('customer.email')], [
            'name' => $request->input('customer.fullname'),
            'email' => $request->input('customer.email'),
            'phone' => $request->input('customer.phone'),
            'country' => $language->getCurrentCountry(),
            'company_name' => $request->input('customer.company_name'),
            'city' => $request->input('customer.city'),
            'optin_newsletter' => $request->input('customer.newsletter')
        ]);

        $product = $products->find($request->input('cart.product_id'));

        $pricing = $product->getCountryPrice($language->getCurrentCountry());

        if (! $pricing)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'error' => trans(self::ERROR_PRODUCT_COUNTRY_UNAVAILABLE, ['productName' => $product->name])
            ], 422);
        }

        $order = $orders->create([
            'customer_id'        => $customer->id,
            'product_id'         => $product->id,
            'product_flavor'     => $request->input('cart.flavor'),
            'amount'             => $pricing->amount,
            'vat_amount'         => $pricing->vat_amount,
            'currency'           => $pricing->currency,
            'carehome_selection' => $request->input('carehome.custom'),
            'carehome_name'      => $request->input('carehome.name'),
            'carehome_type'      => $request->input('carehome.type'),
            'carehome_address'   => $request->input('carehome.address'),
            'carehome_city'      => $request->input('carehome.city'),
            'carehome_notes'     => $request->input('carehome.notes'),
            'custom_message'     => $request->input('gifting_options.message'),
            'is_anonymous'       => $request->input('gifting_options.anonymous'),
            'wants_certificate'  => $request->input('gifting_options.certificate'),
            'status'             => Order::STATUS_PENDING,
            'type'               => $request->input('payment_type')
        ]);

        $mollie = $order->getOrCreateMollie();

        return response()->json([
            'mollie_redirect' => $mollie->getCheckoutUrl()
        ]);
    }
}
```

Also, if I try to remove the API routes temporarily, and still attempt to access them, I weirdly enough get a 404, which means Laravel is able to detect the route, but it's using the wrong Controller's response.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you post part of your OrdersController code? Because you were able to get the 404, I'm assuming you restarted the web service after changing the Routes. I have had to run `php artisan clear:cache` or `php artisan route:cache` before to clear.

Comment: Done @DanielGale

Comment: I also cleared any kind of cache, result does not change.

Comment: You are calling the Url in the response for Controllers@Index
`        return response()->json([
            'mollie_redirect' => $mollie->getCheckoutUrl()
        ]);` Does it have anything to do with that?

Comment: That is in the OrdersController, not the Controller@index. That one is just `return view('index')` essentially.

Comment: So you are telling the OrdersController.store to return the Controller@index view. Try changing that line to `return 'some text'` or `return response()->json(['test'=>'some data']);` and see what you get.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181088/discussion-between-giampy-and-daniel-gale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what @Marcin Nabialek said, it was an issue with one of the headers that should have supposedly been sent with the request. However it was not the `Content-Type` but rather `Accept`.

You must use `Accept: application/json` in order to receive a JSON response for APIs, at least this is how it behaves in Laravel 5.7.6.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried setting up the two headers like suggested above but it wasn't working for me. Instead I've modified the route regex to match urls that doesn't begin with `api` and it worked:

```
Route::view('/{any?}', 'app')
->where('any', '^(?!api).*');
```

Comment: This is unrelated to what my issue was.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - when you remove the api routes, *there is no route* for `POST` method (because your wildcard "catch-all" route is only for `GET` or `HEAD` requests). This is why you get a HTTP 404 - no route found for this request.

If you add the api routes as described in question - the response provided seems to be a raw twig view (possibly a layout). I assume you triple checked that there is no way that your OrdersController would respond that way - if not, try adding `return '{}';` as the first line of your controller and see what happens.

Regardless - it may have something to do with the request type (you set the request header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) - the RouteServiceProvider or perhaps the `api` middleware have something to do with it. Try setting the request header to `application/json` for instance, and dig into the RouteServiceProvider and api middleware.

Comment: I tried to add a `dd('test')` in the store method of OrdersController, but it is never displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What I think is going here is a mix of 2 things:

- You don't set here `Content-Type` to `application/json` so app "thinks" this normal form is sent
- You use custom validation class `OrderCreateRequest` and probably validation failes.  That's why if you put `dd('test');` into your controller method it won't be executed at all

In case validation failes validator throws `ValidationException` exception and implementation what happens in such case looks like this:

```
protected function convertValidationExceptionToResponse(ValidationException $e, $request)
{
    if ($e->response) {
        return $e->response;
    }

    return $request->expectsJson()
                ? $this->invalidJson($request, $e)
                : $this->invalid($request, $e);
}
```

So in case it's AJAX request or Content-Type is set to `application/json` (more or less), then it will return JSON response with failed validation otherwise redirection is made.

Comment: I literally just tried setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json` but without success. I've made sure that validation does not fail, and even if it did, it should give me the validation errors as a JSON object, instead of a wrong response that has nothing to do with the route I am calling.